# Python - Group dataframe based on certain string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to combine these strings and rows within certain logic:

```
s1 = ['abc.txt','abc.txt','ert.txt','ert.txt','ert.txt']
s2 = [1,1,2,2,2]
s3 = ['Harry Potter','Vol 1','Lord of the Rings - Vol 1',np.nan,'Harry Potter']
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(s1,s2,s3)),
            columns=['file','id','book'])
df
```

Data Preview:

```
file     id  book
abc.txt  1   Harry Potter
abc.txt  1   Vol 1
ert.txt  2   Lord of the Rings
ert.txt  2   NaN
ert.txt  2   Harry Potter
```

I have bunch of files name columns with id's associated with it. I have 'book' column where vol 1 has been in separate row. 
I know that this vol1 is only associated with 'Harry Potter' in the given dataset. 
Based on the group by of 'file' & 'id', how do I combine 'Vol 1' in the same row where 'Harry Potter' string appears in the row?
Notice some data row doesn't have vo1 for Harry Potter I only want 'Vol 1' when looking at the file & id groupby.

2 Tries:

1st: doesn't work

```
if (df['book'] == 'Harry Potter' and df['book'].str.contains('Vol 1',case=False) in df.groupby(['file','id'])):
    df.groupby(['file','id'],as_index=False).first()
```

2nd: this applies to every string (but don't want it apply every 'Harry Potter' string.

```
df.loc[df['book'].str.contains('Harry Potter',case=False,na=False), 'new_book'] = 'Harry Potter - Vol 1'
```

Here is the output I am looking for

```
file     id  book
abc.txt  1   Harry Potter - Vol 1
ert.txt  2   Lord of the Rings - Vol 1
ert.txt  2   NaN
ert.txt  2   Harry Potter
```

Comment: Can i check if file -  `ert.txt` id = `2` is right in your example data..? both LOTR and Harry Potter have id `2` in that file..? That makes things awkward if so

Comment: also how did you get `Vol 1` after `Lord of the Rings`?

Comment: That's already in the original df @VnC - just not in the 'preview'

Comment: @VnC 'Lord of the Rings - Vol 1' was cleanly populated, 'Harry Potter' string is the pain full ones. Don't want to assign 'Vol 1' unless it showed up the in file and id combination. It could have been 'Vol 2' but it would be wrong if I said 'Vol 1' for all 'Harry Potter' string, like the 2nd attempt code, hence I want to leave that alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that "Vol x" occurs on the row following the title, I would use an auxilliary Series obtained by shifting the book column by -1. It is then enough to combine that Series with the book column when it starts with `"Vol "` and drop lines where the books column starts with `"Vol "`. Code could be:

```
b2 = df.book.shift(-1).fillna('')
df['book'] = df.book + np.where(b2.str.match('Vol [0-9]+'), ' - ' + b2, '')
print(df.drop(df.loc[df.book.fillna('').str.match('Vol [0-9]+')].index))
```

If the order in the dataframe is not guaranteed but if a *Vol x* row matches the other row in dataframe with same file and id, you can split the dataframe in 2 parts one containing the *Vol x* rows and one containing the other ones and update the latter from the former:

```
g = df.groupby(df.book.fillna('').str.match('Vol [0-9]+'))
for k, v in g:
    if k:
        df_vol = v
    else:
        df = v

for row in df_vol.iterrows():
    r = row[1]
    df.loc[(df.file == r.file)&(df.id==r.id), 'book'] += ' - ' + r['book']
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the code above it work good with the sample data set I provided. After I applied to my data set, I realized 'Harry Potter' string might be in any order in the 'file' & 'id'. So, when I removed 'shift(-1)', it maps it to the next order string. Is possible to only apply to 'Harry Potter' string and nothing else?

Comment: @sharp: The problem is that your example data contains 2 different books (*Lord of the Rings* and again *Harry Potter)* for `file=='ert.txt'` and `id==2`. It has already be noticed in Chris A's comment. So I did not imagine that it could constitute an unique identifier...

Comment: id is not unique to book or file field. It is some id in the file. That's why I need to combine it based on 'file' & 'id' for vol 1

Answer (score 1):

Start from `import re` (you will use it).

Then create your DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'file': ['abc.txt','abc.txt','ert.txt','ert.txt','ert.txt'],
    'id':   [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    'book': ['Harry Potter', 'Vol 1', 'Lord of the Rings - Vol 1',
             np.nan, 'Harry Potter']})
```

The first processing step is to add a column, let's call it *book2*,
containing *book2* from the next row:

```
df["book2"] = df.book.shift(-1).fillna('')
```

I added `fillna('')` to replace *NaN* values with an empty string.

Then define a function to be applied to each row:

```
def fn(row):
    return f"{row.book} - {row.book2}" if row.book == 'Harry Potter'\
        and re.match(r'^Vol \d+$', row.book2) else row.book
```

This function checks whether *book* == "Harry Potter" and *book2* matches
"Vol " + a sequence of digits.
If it does, it returns *book* + *book2*, otherwise it returns just *book*.

Then we apply this function and save the result back under *book*:

```
df["book"] = df.apply(fn, axis=1)
```

And the only remaining thing is to drop:

- rows where *book* matches *Vol \d+*,
- *book2* column.

The code is:

```
df = df.drop(df[df.book.str.match(r'^Vol \d+$').fillna(False)].index)\
    .drop(columns=['book2'])
```

*fillna(False)* is needed because *str.match* returns *NaN* for
source content ==  *NaN*.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing `merge`, `apply`, `update`, `drop_duplicates`.

`set_index` and `merge` on index `file`, `id` between df of `'Harry Potter'` and `df` of `'Vol 1'`; `join` to create appropriate string and convert it to dataframe

```
df.set_index(['file', 'id'], inplace=True)
df1 = df[df['book'] == 'Harry Potter'].merge(df[df['book'] == 'Vol 1'], left_index=True, right_index=True).apply(' '.join, axis=1).to_frame(name='book')

Out[2059]:
                          book
file    id
abc.txt 1   Harry Potter Vol 1
```

Update original `df`, `drop_duplicate`, and `reset_index`

```
df.update(df1)
df.drop_duplicates().reset_index()

Out[2065]:
      file  id                       book
0  abc.txt   1         Harry Potter Vol 1
1  ert.txt   2  Lord of the Rings - Vol 1
2  ert.txt   2                        NaN
3  ert.txt   2               Harry Potter
```